# How to fix unresolved reference:imageView error in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have a problem in my foodview.imageView.setImageResource(food.image!!) the error is unresolved reference:imageView

```
override fun getView(index: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        var food :Food = this.foodlist[index]
        var inflater :LayoutInflater = context!!.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        var foodview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout,null)
        foodview.imageView.setImageResource(food.image!!)
        foodview.textView.text = food.name!!
        return foodview
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to set the image using setImageResource() the parameter you passing must be an int for example.  setImageResource(R.drawable.image). Check the value of your variable food.image